# Saving file using file saver is not working on chrome iPhone but works on safari?

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to save file on click but it works only on safari ... I am using file save for this.

```js
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

// from doc 
// FileSaver saveAs(Blob/File/Url, optional DOMString filename, optional Object { autoBom })


// Current implmentation that works only on safari 
const save = () => {
    const text = 'bla bla bla'
    saveAs(new Blob([text]), 'file.txt', { autoBom: true });
};
```